# Can we have a java client for a servlet in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, encryption

I need to have a client application ruuning on my local host, that takes data from user, encrypts it and sends the encrypted data (BigInteger) to a servlet in the Google App Engine.

The servlet should then perform some operations on the data and send the result to the client application. Then the client decrypts the result and displays it to the user.

What is the most appropriate way to implement this? Given that I have used Eclipse with Google Plugin to create the servlet and deploy it. Do I have to make any changes to the index.html and other .xml files. What type of project should my client app be and should I link it to the servlet?

Kindly, guide me as I am totally new to this concept!

Comment: It sounds like you just need to have your client app do an http request to the url of the servlet.

Comment: I had done that but it didnt work! i had created a client applet in my system but the servlet is unable to find my applet it says. Kindly, refer to my previous (more elaborate) question regarding this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371956/communication-between-an-applet-and-a-servlet-deployed-in-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

Inside **web.xml** add this code for session on for every user.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
```

here 15 means 15min session on for 1user.

and **appengine-web.xml** add

```
<!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
  <!--
```

Comment: It gives me the following error when i deploy it after making above changes. "An internal error occurred during: "Deploying paillierserver to Google".
XML error validating C:\Users\Zakir Hussain\Desktop\Thesis\project\eclipse workspace\paillierserver\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml against C:\Users\Zakir Hussain\Desktop\Thesis\project\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.3\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.3\docs\appengine-web.xsd "